# ul, li list expanding inapropriatel

Tags: html, css, html-lists

see i have this inline blocked list and I want to display it vertically in the small screens for phones, the problem is the ul is not expanding appropriately. 
I have this hierarchy:

```
div
 ul
   li (1)
      ul
         li
         li
         li
   li (2)
      ul
         li
         li
         li
```

when I press on li(1) the ul under it expands but li(2) keeps in its position, however it is supposed to localize under the items expanded, I have added a picture, I hope it will make my query clearer.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fmc5.png)

what display should I add to the outer div or to the outer ul, to make this list displays as the appropriate hierarchy.

Comment: Post your code (html and css). Otherwise nobody can help :)

Comment: We'll need to see `css` relevant and applicable to your list items and sub-menus as well, otherwise we'll just be taking educated guesses, like; "it's probably a *stacking context* issue caused by `absolute` positioned elements. Declare a `z-index` property or use `position: relative` instead, so that nested list items and sub-menus remain in the document flow and affect each other intuitively in the layout when changes occur"